# What are the chords used to end blues songs like "One Way Out"?

Tags: electric-guitar, blues

The ending to "One Way Out" as done by the Allman Brothers Band has an ending that is common to lots of blues songs.  It follows what sounds like a descending run like a normal turnaround with the ending being two chords with a beautiful minor/flat sound.  What are these chords and how do they fit into the standard blues form?  Here is the [song](https://youtu.be/Gg54zkr6IWs).

Comment: Yes, hearing this song recently just reminded me that I've wondered about that ending that sounds the same for lots of songs for a long time.  Being the blues, I shouldn't have been surprised that it's a simple variation of a turnaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed one variation of a standard blues cliché. The chords they play are

`| A  A7/C#  D7  D#dim7 |  A  Adim7  A7  |`

Note the chromatically ascending bass line in the first bar:

`A C# D D#`

which would often lead to an A7/E chord, i.e. the chromatic line would continue up to the E. The descending melody line you hear could be

`| A G F# F# | E Eb E |`

There is also a cliché melody line which would really descend chromatically from the G to the E (i.e., it would replace the second F# in the above line with an F), but it doesn't fit these chords. For that chromatic line to work you would need to replace the D#dim7 chord with a Dm7, which is one other variation of this classic progression.

This progression can be played at the end of a (blues) song, as in "One Way Out". With a slight variation it can also be played as a standard turn-around in the last two bars of a 12-bar blues. As a turn-around the progression leads back to the V7 chord (E7), which, in turn, leads back to the beginning of the next 12-bar verse/chorus:

`| A  A7/C#  D7  D#dim7 |  A  F7  E7  |`

Comment: Can I assume from the bass line that this is a major blues song?  If it were minor blues wouldn't the notes be from the natural C scale?

Comment: @PJNoes: It's a blues in A, this means that the root chord is A7 (which has a major third). It's not a minor blues, but normally you wouldn't call it "major blues". Note that the chords of a blues are usually not based on one single scale.